# Install script as service running under speciffied user

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts

I would like to install services into init.d folder in most standard way. Suppose I have script which should be run under specific user and starts the service (tomcat8 good example)

> .../serviceFoo/start.sh

another script

> .../serviceFoo/stop.sh

Now I want to install this as init.d startup scripts so I can /etc/init.d.seviceFoo start|stop|restart. 
   It would be nice if the service would get killed after some time refusing to stop by issuing stop command. 
   It would be even nicer if i can do it by running simple command like

> installService user startScript stopScript

Is there something like that in ubuntu ? something like brand new sysv-rc-conf with add button ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com). Look specifically at the [setuid](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid) command.